# Need help to solve these two trigonometric functions?

Tags: functions, trigonometry

I can't figure out how to solve these functions. Any help or links to examples on how to do these will be much appreciated.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RbAbV.jpg)

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Please type your questions instead of posting images.  Images can't be browsed and are not accessible to those using screen readers.  If you need help formatting math on this site, here's a [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: ok thanks will try to rework it

Comment: yeah it deos thanks